# CMS Pages are not adding blocks in {{ }} SUPEE-6788

Tags: cms, static-block

On Magento 1.9.2.2 patch1 a cms page content disappears when I add a block like:

`{{block type="imprint/field" value="shop_name"}}`.

If I remove it, the page (text) content is back again.

Anybody an idea where this could come from? It is the same with all blocks added like this.

Comment: i have usure that "if u remove ` {{block type="imprint/field" value="shop_name"}}.` then that page are totally blank

Comment: did you add them to your block whitelist?

Comment: Block whitelist? What is this?

Comment: I I remoce {{block ... }} the other text content of the pages is beeing shown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to whitelist your block types. You can add them with your database installation script or add them manually in `System > Permissions > Blocks`:

> Magento now includes a white list of allowed blocks or directives. If
>   a module or extension uses variables like {{config
>   path=”web/unsecure/base_url”}} and {{block type=rss/order_new}} in CMS
>   pages or emails, and the directives are not on this list, you will
>   need to add them with your database installation script. Extensions or
>   custom code that handles content (like blog extensions) might be
>   affected.
>
> - See more at: http://magento.com/security/patches/supee-6788-technical-details#sthash.QpgvH62l.dpuf

Answer (score 0):

***As  alternative solution***.

---

goto Design tab of Your cms page

Put below `layout xml  code` at *`Layout Update XML field`*

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="imprint/field" value="shop_name" />
</reference>
```

Hope i will resolve ur issue

Comment: Hi Amit. No it does not. No changes. It is concerning ALL Blocks, not just this one.... at least every block I put in like that {{block ... }}